# how to generate hql query for OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have brands class which is mapped as ONE TO ONE with Specification class `MobileBrands.class`:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private int price;
@OneToOne
private MobileSpecification prodInfo;
```

The `MobileSpecification.class`:

```
private int id;
private String ram;
private String rom;
@OneToOne
private MobileBrands brands;
```

I know sql which works fine.

SQL:

```
select mobile_brands.id, mobile_brands.name, specification.ram, specification.rom 
        from mobile_brands inner join specification on 
            mobile_brands.brand_id=specification.ID where mobile_brands.BRAND_ID='1'
```

And though I'm new to HQL Query so this what I have tried:

```
SELECT u.id as id, u.name as name, 
    u.prodInfo.ram as ram, u.prodInfo.rom as rom from MobileBrands inner join MobileSpecification 
        with MobileBrands.id=MobileSpecification.id where MobileBrands.id='1'"
```

Which doesn't work (HQL one). How to convert it to HQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from:

```
SELECT u.id as id, u.name as name, 
u.prodInfo.ram as ram, u.prodInfo.rom as rom from MobileBrands inner join MobileSpecification 
    with MobileBrands.id=MobileSpecification.id where MobileBrands.id='1'"
```

To:

```
select new com.package.app.MobileDto(mb.id, md.name, ms.rom, ms.ram) FROM MobileBrands mb, MobileSpecification ms WHERE mb.id = 1 and mb.id = ms.id
```

As you see, I'm using a MbDto class to receive each information. You can create this class on the package (per example) `com.package.app` with a constructor for the fields:

```
class MbDto {

    MbDto(int id, String name, String ram, String rom) {
         // constructor will all fields
    }
}
```

Using it if you expect only one result (example):

```
String jpql = "select new com.package.app.MobileDto(mb.id, md.name, ms.rom, ms.ram) FROM MobileBrands mb, MobileSpecification ms WHERE mb.id = 1 and mb.id = ms.id";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
MbDto mbDto = query.getSingleResult();
```

The newer versions of Hibernate is possible to make a JOIN without relationship, but this is not necessary for your problem.

But pay attention that you are not using the mapped relationship between these two entities. If you trying to do that, the query would be:

```
select mb FROM MobileBrands mb JOIN mb.productInfo pi WHERE mb.id = 1
```

Comment: Though I have not tried your approach but my requirement is I need some specific property from **MobileBrands** and it's associated **MobileSpecifiaction** class. Like my MobileBrands and MobileSpecification contain many properties but i nedd some  **selected**  properties from MobileBrands and MobileSpecification. I think this approach will give the whole class properties but I wnt to reduce the query generation by selecting specific property

Comment: This is also possible. You can choose the properties and use a `Dto` to bring these values. I will add that to my answer

Comment: @RiaMohanty see my answer again